# Querying the images of an product in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-queryset

Can anyone help me to get just the images of an product?

I have these two models:

```
class Product(models.Model):
    name=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
    price=models.DecimalField(max_digits=7,decimal_places=2)
    description=models.TextField(blank=True,null=True)
    image=models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True,default="images/default.jpg")
    size=models.ManyToManyField(Size)
    digital=models.BooleanField(default=False,null=True,blank=True)
    categories = models.ForeignKey(Category,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,blank=True, null=True) 
    objects = models.Manager() 

class Images(models.Model):
    product=models.ForeignKey(Product,on_delete=models.SET_NULL,null=True,blank=True)
    title=models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True,blank=True)
    image=models.ImageField(blank=True,null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.title) if self.title else 'image'
```

and in my views.py I use this query to get the images of just a specific product but I get all the images of all the products

```
query = Images.objects.all().query
    query.group_by=['product']
    img=QuerySet(query=query)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply fetch the `Product` ojects of a single product with:

```
myproduct.images_set.all()
```

where `myproduct` is a `Product` object.

If you have only the primary key of the product, you can filter with:

```
Images.objects.filter(product_id=id_of_product)
```

---

> **Note**: normally a Django model is given a *singular* name, so `Image` instead of <s>`Images`</s>.